# unable to startup tomcat server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I was unable to start up my application on server after I change the applicatino into spring webflow application

`Nov 10, 2015 11:53:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.64
Nov 10, 2015 11:53:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/j2eeapplication]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/j2eeapplication]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name Resources Servlet
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3307)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3286)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5405)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more`

is there any other configuration i have to do?

this is my web.xml

```
<display-name>J2EE Applications Example</display-name><welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file></welcome-file-list> <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value></context-param>context-param>    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
<param-value>.xhtml</param-value> </context-param>  <context-param> <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></context-param>  <context-param>   <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name><param-value>1</param-value>  </context-param><listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  </listener><servlet><servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class><load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup></servlet><servlet-mapping><servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern></servlet-mapping><servlet><servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name><servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class><init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup></servlet><servlet-mapping><servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern></servlet-mapping> <servlet><servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name><servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup></servlet><servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>.jsf</url-pattern></servlet-mapping><filter><filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param></filter><filter-mapping><filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

sorry the syntax of my web.xml in stackoverflow code sample typo abit mix up together

Comment: i had editted my question, sorry about the web.xml arrangement mixed up

Comment: see [servlet mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html), you missed <servlet></servlet> for Faces Servlet

Comment: thanks both of you I found the problem it was 

.jsf in the url-pattern, must be *.jsf

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by adding "*" before .jsf in url-pattern tag